# Typography gets pixileted in online version

Tags: jquery, html, typography

I'm working on this site www.runebs.dk and have problem with the typography. When the site is on my localhost the typography looks fine but when I upload it to the server it gets really pixelated.

I have tried to change the typography but that doesn't work. I might think it could be something in this script underneath because it's only in the divs the script displays, where the typography is pixilated. The typography looks fine on the rest of the site.

Is it because the script prints the content twice or?

Here is the online version https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT3bi.jpg
And here is the local version https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zgZs.jpg

I really hope someone in here can point me in the right direction..

the html...

```
<div id="subHeadline">
   <h3 class="h3 title"></h3>
   <h3><div class="year"></div></h3>
   <h3><div class="description"></div></h3>
   <h3 class="showHide">(–)</h3>
</div>

<header class="article-header">
   <h3 class="h3 title">title text</h3>

<div class="year">
    <h3>year text</h3>
</div>

<div class="description">
   description text
</div>

    <h3 class="showHide"></h3>
```

the css..

```
.article-header { display: none;}
 #subHeadline {position:fixed; top:0px; left: 0; margin-left: 22px; padding-top: 64px; height:   auto; width: 600px; z-index:1; }
 #subHeadline .description { display: block; width: 255px; position: relative; margin-top: 28px;}
 #subHeadline .showHide  { display: none; width: 255px; position: relative; margin-top: 28px; cursor: pointer;}
.year {display: block; margin-top: -19px;}
```

and the jquery...

```
function toggleInfo () {
 $('.showHide').on('click',function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
 $( '#subHeadline .description' ).slideToggle(200);
 var currentState = $(this).text();
 console.log('state: ', currentState);
 if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.showHide').empty();
    $(this).text('(+)');
} else {
  $(this).text('(–)');
}
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    // firing toggleInfo when doc ready
     toggleInfo();

var $window = $(window);

$window.trigger('scroll'); // init the value

$window.on('scroll', function(){

var pos = $('#subHeadline').offset();
  $('.article-header').each(function(){
      if (pos.top <= $(this).offset().top && pos.top >= $(this).next().offset().top) {
        var desc = $('.description', this).text();
        var title = $('.h3', this).text();
        var year = $('.year', this).text();
        var button = $('.showHide', this).text();
          $('#subHeadline .title').text(title);
          $('#subHeadline .year').text(year);
          $('#subHeadline .description').text(desc);
          $('#subHeadline .showHide').show();
          return;
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: What font are you using locally on your page?  Can you include your stylesheet (s) as well?

Comment: it's really silly that new users aren't allowed to include pictures in their posts. a screenshot of the problem would have been useful here (i'm not faulting you).

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow  People can upload them to imgur or other image sharing site manually and link to it.

Comment: I have edited with image and css.. many thanks..

Comment: are you using the same browser to view both the online and local version?

Comment: yes I'm using chrome, but it looks even worse in safari

Comment: If the difference is between online and local version, how are we expected to figure it out without access to the local version? Moreover, the code posted is not HTML; it contains PHP instructions, so it is not what a browser gets or what would work in a truly local page (which is not even on a local HTTP server).

Comment: I know it's not likely the issue, but having valid markup to start is a good way to eliminate things that are potentially causing issues.  `DIV` tags according to the W3 are not valid within `H3` or other heading / inline level elements.  A quick run through the validator will reveal the issues.  Also, your JS will always throw an error on the last header when you check the position (since you reference `next()` before checking to see if there is a next).

Comment: Also, I am unable to reproduce the issue in a fiddle (though I am not sure what the code should be doing).  So, it would appear to be an issue with your production server.  You can fork this if you need to make tweaks to better illustrate how your code behaves: http://jsfiddle.net/pw4jkb75/5/

Comment: Okay thanks I will try to make the fiddle..

Comment: sorry I can't get it to work in fiddle as well.. http://jsfiddle.net/9asnw1c3/1/ I might have to find a person how can see it live..

Comment: your fonts are located in `../fonts/..` if you look at the net console you can see that the font you would like to use is not found. Do you have have the font installed on your local maschine? you need to set the correct path to the font in the css, that's it, nothing else

Comment: I have change the path.. The weird thing is that if you change the font to helvetica or georgia it is still really pixelated so i don't think it's something with the font.. But something in the code..